# Custom properties for reports in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a customized report sitemap for SSRS (which is a report itself) and currently put custom options in the report description. I then use those options in the sitemap to filter reports accordingly.

I was wondering if I could add columns to the ReportServer.dbo.Catalog table?
Or is there a way to add custom properties to the report settings (as in picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering the Catalog table in the SSRS database would more than likely break SSRS. At a minimum, it would stop you from being able to upgrade to another version in the future without a whole lot of pain.

If you really need to add custom properties to the report catalog, host your reports in SharePoint. That way, you can add additional fields to the report list it creates all day long, and you won't break a thing.

I have done this, it's nice. I have added a new field to hold the technical description of the report, leaving the canned description field for the business description. With SharePoint, you can all sorts of additional fields, for all types of data. If you know anything about the SharePoint database, you can query that too to pull the addition data into whatever you need.

This may not be the answer you want since the move to SharePoint may not be an option for you, but it is a viable option none the less.